# services with sensor_msgs::Image response in diamondback ubuntu10.10

Tags: sensor-msgs, opencv2, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am making some set of nodes for which I want grab images from a camera(usb) only at certain times and I need very strict timings to do evaluation. I have created a service to return a `sensor_msgs::Image img` as a response. But I keep getting

`error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘res->perception_srvs::GetRawImageResponse_<std::allocator<void> >::img = sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(const IplImage*, std::string)(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"passthrough"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())))))`
`

when doing `res.img = cv_bridge_converter.cvToImgMsg(current_img)` with *current_img* being an IplImage.

I have checked the *polled_camera* package as option, but it still does not give me the flow I need. Publishing the images for me will be an overkill, I just need to move them around at very few and specific instances.

Here is my code snippet for this piece

```
`// some code`
camera >> current_img;
try
{
  IplImage img = current_img;
  res.img = cv_converter.cvToImgMsg(&img, "passthrough"); 
}
catch (sensor_msgs::CvBridgeException e)
{
  ROS_ERROR("CvBridge conversion exception, [%s]", e.what());
}
// some more code
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9216/services-with-sensor_msgs::image-response-in-diamondback-ubuntu10.10/) by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1295 on 2011-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) API changed significantly in Diamondback. I suggest you take a look at the [C++ tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) again and make sure you select "diamondback" in the version selector at the top of the page.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1